# handling 404 page not found error not overriding the default in Next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my app directory in Next js 13 I've created a file `not-found.jsx` as the docs suggested to handle 404 errors. but it is not overriding the default 404 page. and i created that inside of app directory itself as i would use the layout and loading.

this is what i used in `not-found.jsx`

```
import React from "react";

function NotFound() {
  return (
    <main class="grid min-h-full place-items-center bg-white px-6 py-24 sm:py-32 lg:px-8">
      <div class="text-center">
        <p class="text-base font-semibold text-indigo-600">404</p>
        <h1 class="mt-4 text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl">
          Page not found
        </h1>
        <p class="mt-6 text-base leading-7 text-gray-600">
          Sorry, we couldn’t find the page you’re looking for.
        </p>
        <div class="mt-10 flex items-center justify-center gap-x-6">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3.5 py-2.5 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
          >
            Go back home
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900">
            Contact support <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default NotFound;
```

Comment: It's working for me. Can yo show your file structure?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar the code for the `not-found.js` is in the question nad i am using it directly in the app folder. meaning the root page. but if it helps i created the project 3 months ago when next 13 first released. maybe it's changed

Comment: Yeah, lots of things have changed since, like the `app` folder has become stable. I would suggest you upgrade your project.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar actually for some reasons it worked when i created 404.jsx inside the old pages folder.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you still are looking for the solution, maybe this help.

create `404.jsx` inside pages folder to override the default not found page. but if you are working with dynamic routing, then you can use the new `not-found.jsx` for that route.